# Making URL clickable in a textbox in a PDF file with Acrobat XI Pro

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, hyperlink

I sometime add text in PDF with Acrobat XI Pro:

[image]

In the added text, I sometime write URLs. Is there an easy way to make them clickable?

I am aware that I can make a zone clickable by using [Tools > Content > Link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7cb7.w.html), but it's tedious, and I then have to format the URL so that it appears as being clickable (change color and/or underline it): I would much prefer some feature that allow me to select the URL and ask me something like "make it clickable?". Or even better, by default, making any URL I type clickable.

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt you'll have much luck, as an active hyperlink is not simple plain-text.  Notice how the Add Text and Add Link functions are separate?   Anyhow, someone might have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I write a URL by using the Edit Text & Images it works as a clickable link when I reopen the PDF File.

I did write the link like this though `http://www.google.com`

---

From [How to Make Clickable Links in a PDF](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_make_clickable_links_pdf) Article it sounds like different PDF viewers handle the links inside a PDF differently as well, I don't know if this has anything to do with the issue that you are having, but it may be worth a thought at least.

The Question was

> I created a document in Microsoft Word with lots of hyperlinks, but when I save the document as a PDF file, the hyperlinks are not clickable. Do you know what I have to do to make these links clickable?

and the answer starts out

> This is a strange phenomenon with Microsoft Word that we never noticed until you pointed it out. It appears that the hyperlinks inside your PDF file are clickable if you open your PDF in Adobe Reader, but not in Apple’s Preview. But since most Mac users use Preview to read their PDF files, you can never be assured that your recipients will be able to click on your links.